# hey guys am new to flutter and dart and I need help. I was following a tutorial and I have this problem. it says "Expected to find ','." at bodyImage

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar:AppBar(
          title: Text("I am rich"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        )
      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
      body: Image(
          image: NetworkImage('https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png')

      )
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You forgot to put `,` at the end of AppBar.

Answer (score 0):

Your Answer is

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar:AppBar(
          title: Text("I am rich"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
      body: Image(
          image: NetworkImage('https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png')

      )
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Just Copy And Paste The Code That I Have Added

Comment: Thank u so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(
  MaterialApp(
  home:Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    appBar:AppBar(
      title: Text("I am rich"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    ), //I edited. you add , this point *********
  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
  body: Image(
      image: NetworkImage('https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png')

      )
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: Suggestion to improve your answers: Adding comment inside the code is not always obvious, it would  be good to have a some non-code formatted comments at the start of your answer to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "," at your AppBar

```
    appBar:AppBar(
      title: Text("I am rich"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    ), // This comma is missing
```

In analysis_options.yaml you can add `require_trailing_commas: true` (experimental) to your linter options, this will force you to use comma's everywhere and will make your code more legible in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code you miss the `,` before body I think you refer AppBar Widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)  from documentation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(
         MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("I am rich"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
            ),
            body: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Your Result screen-> [image]